# Substitution yielding linear function for least squares fitting

Tags: optimization, regression, least-squares, substitution

I have an independent variable $\delta$ and dependent set of statistical classified data $\widehat{\Lambda }(\delta)$.
The model I want to fit to this data is:
$$
\Lambda (\delta )=Ae^{-k\delta}*f(k)
$$
There are many cases but for this example we assume:
$$
f(k)=\frac{2}{k^2\sigma ^2}\big(e^{\frac{k^2\sigma ^2}{2}\Delta T}-1\big)
$$
Note:$\Delta T$ and $\sigma$ are known variables.

In the white paper I've got this equation there was this equation given for the sum of the squared errors, that needs to be minimized:
$$
r(A,k)=\sum_{\delta=1}^{\delta_{max}}\bigg(\log\big(\widehat{\Lambda}(\delta)\big)+k\delta-\log\big(A\big)-\log\big(f(k)\big)\bigg)^2
$$
Now since $f(k)$ is not dependent on $\delta$ I would substitute:
$$
u=A*f(k)
$$
Which gives you this equation as the model:
$$
\Lambda(\delta)=ue^{-k\delta}
$$
The function of the squared errors that needs to be minimized for this quasilinear model is :
$$
r(A,k)=\sum_{\delta=1}^{\delta_{max}}\bigg(\log\big(\widehat{\Lambda}(\delta)\big)+k\delta-\log\big(u\big)\bigg)^2
$$
Now we have a linear equation we need to do our regression for, which is way easier than any non-linear approach.
And with $k$ and $\log(u)$ in hand we can easily solve for $A$

I did some back tests with scipy's optimization functions and I got the same results when I optimized the parameters $A$ and $k$ with the initial model and the Levenberg-Marquardt optimization function, and when I tried fit $\log(u)$ and $k$ with the linear least squares fitting approach by hand and then solved for $A$.

But I want to ask you, the experts, if this is really mathematically justified.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This same logarithmic transformation is discussed in [Least squares fit for exponential function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488747/least-square-approximation-for-exponential-functions/2163333#2163333)

To summarize, the logarithmic transform distorts the data. The solution does *not* find the parameters $A$ and $k$ which minimizes the original equation.

However, one can use the method of least squares in the core of the problem. The trick is to fix $k$ and then the problem is linear. Solve for $A$, the compute $r^{2}$. Scan along $k$ to find the minimum $r^{2}$.

The good news is that the least squares problem takes its simplest form: the average. Now, to define the problem. Consider a sequence of $m$ measurements of the form $\left\{ \delta_{j}, \Lambda_{j} \right\}_{j=1}^{m}$. For fixed $k$ we have the linear system
$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    e^{-k \delta_{1}} f(k) \\
      \vdots \\
    e^{-k \delta_{m}} f(k) 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    A
  \end{array}
\right]
%
  =
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \Lambda (\delta_{1}) \\
    \vdots \\
    \Lambda (\delta_{m})
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
With the restriction $f(k) \ne 0$, a more recognizable form is
$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
      \vdots \\
    1 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    A
  \end{array}
\right]
%
  =
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{1})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{1}} \\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{m})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{m}}
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
The least squares solution is the average:
$$
  A(k) = m^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{j})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{j}}
$$
To connect this with least squares, note this solution is given by the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:
$$
A(k) =
% 
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
      \vdots \\
    1 
  \end{array}
\right]^{\dagger}
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{1})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{1}} \\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{m})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{m}}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
=
m^{-1} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{array}\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{1})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{1}} \\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\Lambda (\delta_{m})} {f(k)} e^{k\delta_{m}}
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
Now the target of minimization, the sum of the squares of the residuals, is a function of $k$
$$
  r^{2}(k) = 
\Bigg\lVert
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    e^{-k \delta_{1}} f(k) \\
      \vdots \\
    e^{-k \delta_{m}} f(k) 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    A(k)
  \end{array}
\right]
-
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \Lambda (\delta_{1}) \\
    \vdots \\
    \Lambda (\delta_{m})
  \end{array}
\right]
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2}
%
=
%
\sum_{j=1}^{m} \left( e^{-k \delta_{j}} f(k) A(k) - \Lambda(\delta_{j}) \right)^{2}.
$$

The least squares solution for your problem is defined as
$$
k_{LS} = \left\{ k\in\mathbb{R} \colon r^{2}(k) \text{ is minimized}\right\}.
$$